# How to correctly use javascript:alert(document.lastModified); to check a website last update?

Tags: javascript

I read many webpages. They said that I could use javascript:alert(document.lastModified); to find the last update of a site. I test at least 10 websites. Only the website that I made gives me the right information. All the others show the current time. E.g. "http://automationgt.com/".

Comment: Web sites generated dynamically may lie about the lastModified date.  You cannot trust it to give you useful information.  I doubt there is any way to reliable do this.

Answer (score -1):

I do a site search in Google (e.g. site:pcornet.org ) and then find the page(s) I am looking for using keywords with the site search (e.g. site:pcornet.org intitle:"patient council"). The result will have a date next to it. I figure this is the date that Google reads that it was modified. It's better than having no date at all.

Comment: https://archive.org/web/ might give you a better history.

Comment: Google doesn't always show these dates. It only shows them if the actual page content also shows a date, such as in news articles etc.